# Printing string and variables to glwindow

Tags: c++, screen

I have been looking to an answer to this for a while now but I can't really find one.
I'm not using glut so please no glut only answer.

What I am trying to do is send variables and text to the in game screen so I can make an UI with a little feedback for the player, like the amount of money they are carrying at that moment. (So not the debug screen)

I'm using c++ with opengl.

If I need to provide anyone with more information, please ask and I will do my best to provide you with it.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can live with GL1.x, use the classic reference on bitmap fonts: http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/bitmap_fonts/17002/

If you need something relevant, modify the sample above to use Vertex Arrays / Vertex Buffer Objects and not the glRasterPos functions.

Advanced way is to use the FreeType to render truetype fonts. Here's a [sample](http://damianpaz.wordpress.com/2011/10/09/load-truetype-fonts-with-freetype2-and-build-an-opengl-vertex-array-to-render-text/).

Comment: Okay, today I excepted this answer because I think it works, not sure yet because some other issues are keeping me from checking if it truly works. When I have the working code I will place it here for anyone that is interested.

Comment: Thanks. Just to notice, I'm not giving answers which I haven't tried myself :) My way to go is to use the FreeType and manage the VBOs myself.

Comment: Hey, I tryed to fix the problem and noticed the CreateFont function was the things that is giving trouble because it seams the font is always NULL and the function it self doesn't seam to work at all as I can't step into it during the debugging mode. Is there a replacement for this function or should I go for the other example? If so what do I need to install to be able to use the freetype.h 's becouse my computer can't find.